# How to set X and Y axis Title

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have imported:

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.fugure_format = 'retina'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

to show:

```
plt.plot(train_losses, label='Training loss')
plt.plot(test_losses, label='Test/Validation loss')
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

[image: graph]

I have tried `plt.xlabel('X axis title')` and `plt.ylabel('Y axis title`) and several other codes but none are working.

I'm just trying to label the x, y axis.

Comment: Does `plt.show()` display them?

Comment: `plt.xlabel('X axis title')` will set the x label. So if that isn't working for you please provide a [mcve] and update the question with the versions you are using.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm not sure how to reproduce this code, it is DL neural network results,.. i guess you can use for x axis `x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and `y = 5,4,3,2,1` and just make two lines in graph using my imported modules..

Comment: @YaakovBressler no it didn't work, when i use `plt.xlabel('X axis title')` i get error `'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Yes, it should be independent of the actual data. Of course if I use some generic list like 1,2,3 etc I do get the correct result. So *you* need to make it reproducible.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So if you use a generic list with same imported modules it works? Wouldn't that same code that you used with generic list, if you used code above ie. (%matplotlib inline.....) work in my case... otherwise, if not, it is implying that the error is in the data that is preventing plt.xlabel to work

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest maybe the problem was in the method that I called to do `.plt ...`, there could be another way with other modules..

Comment: In your code, you should use lists like 1,2,3 and rerun the code. See what happens and report about the error/problem you get with those sample data.

Comment: One of the points of making a _minimal_ reproducible example is that in the course of creating it you might realize the error is somewhere else entirely, which is something only _you_ can do (since you did not provide a _reproducible_ example - but providing a 1000-lines-of-code example that runs is problematic for other reasons).

Answer (score 9):

See let us consider that your dataset to make the graph can be divided into 4 parts,train_losses_x,train_losses_y,test_losses_x and test_losses_y.So it can be used as following

```
fig,ax=plt.subplot()
train_line=ax.plot(train_losses_x,train_losses_y,label="Training Loss")
test_line=ax.plot(test_losses_x,test_losses_y,label="Test/Validation Loss")
ax.set_xlabel("X_axis_title")
ax.set_ylabel("Y_axis_title")
legend = ax.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use xlabel and ylabel functions to print string.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
time = [2001,2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006]
population = ["100Lakh","200Lakh", "300Lakh", "400Lakh", "500Lakh", "600Lakh"]
# x = time, y = population
plt.plot(time, population)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("Popluation of city")
plt.show()
```