# how to Change matplotlib.figure.Figure objects axis names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have matplotlib.figure.Figure object named as fig1 and  which contains

```
>>> fig1
```

[image]

Now that I wants to change  Y ( axis secondary)  name from

> **Bad probability**

to

> **Event probability**

I also wants to change title  from

> **Hour**

to

> **Hours to Event**

but i could not find how to achive that.
There are several solution present on stack overflow like

[How to set X and Y axis Title in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447079/how-to-set-x-and-y-axis-title-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

but they explains changing plot title while creating graph where as i am having graph object already created and I just wants to change axis names and title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can see, I suppose you plot two axes on the same figure with `twinx()`.
If you want to change the labels of the last created axis (in your case the line plot) than you can use the `gca()` shortcut (Get Current Axes) to set the label as follows:

```
fig1.gca().set_ylabel("Event probability")
```

The figure title can be set with:

```
fig1.suptitle("Hours to Event")
```

Comment: Thanks  czeni for sharing this solved my problem but I am also curious what if I plot same 3 plots in same figure and wants to change  2nd plots parameters.

Comment: @MangeshDivate Typically in Matplotlib if you call a function that draws something on a figure (or you call the `twinx()`) it returns the related object. Than, you can use that object to adjust its parameters.
For example in your case, when you call `twinx()` it returns the axis object and you do not need to use the `gca()` shortcut, so `twin_ax=ax.twinx(); twin_ax.set_ylabel("todo")` is basically equivalent to `ax.twinx(); fig1.gca().set_ylabel("todo")`